# Запрос MySQL, определение алиаса

Tags: php, веб-программирование, mysql

Есть у меня запрос к БД, редактировал его для добавления еще одного алиаса SPV.term, но не понимаю как добавить необходимые условия. Сейчас выдает ошибку Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'S.id' in 'on clause'.

```
$query = "SELECT  SP.url, SP.id, S.name, SP.hit, SP.hot, SP.action, SP.id, SP.smallimage, SP.mainmodimage,
        (SELECT stock FROM shop_product_variants WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id AND stock > 0 LIMIT 1) as              stock,
        (SELECT price FROM shop_product_variants WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
        OR shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id AND stock = 0 LIMIT 1) as price,
        (SELECT id FROM shop_product_variants WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id
        OR shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id AND stock = 0 LIMIT 1) as v_id,
        (SELECT old_price FROM shop_product_variants WHERE shop_product_variants.product_id = S.id AND stock > 0 LIMIT 1)   as old_price
                FROM shop_products_i18n S, shop_product_variants SPV
                INNER JOIN shop_products SP ON SP.id = S.id
                WHERE SP.active = 1 AND S.name LIKE '%" . $get . "%'
        OR SPV.term LIKE '%" . $get . "%'
                GROUP BY S.id
                ORDER BY stock DESC ";
```

Comment: Оказывается надо было нормально настроить джоины:
INNER JOIN shop_products SP ON SP.id = S.id
INNER JOIN shop_product_variants SPV ON SPV.product_id = SP.id

Answer (score 1):

вложенные запросы не будут знать о вашем внешнем алиасе `FROM shop_products_i18n S`

Comment: Освежите [матчасть](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html)